# How to enter the text into 'textarea' tag using selenium?

Tags: selenium, textarea

I want to enter the text "ABCD" as shown in the below image of
https://translate.google.com/

Tried the following ways but failed.

1. sendKeys()--failed.

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id='sourceis']")).sendKeys("ABCD");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id='source-is']")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB"ABCD");
2. set the value property using JavaScriptExecutor--failed

   JavascriptExecutor js =  (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
           js.executeScript("document.getElementById('source-is').setAttribute('value', 'ABCD')");
3. first clear() field and then sendKeys()--failed.

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id='source-is']")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id='source-is']")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB,"ABCD");

Please provide the solution to get it done.

[image: textarea field]

Comment: mention the environment like selenium, browser, os and java versions along with the code. with @optimist_creeper code, it is working for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you tried but the following code works:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("source")).sendKeys("your text to enter");
```

Comment: Did you try with ID? Take a look at your x-path. I think it is mistyped. Id should be 'source' only not 'source-is' or 'sourceis'.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in the Selenium IDE Firefox (v68) extension:

- Command: `execute script`
- Target : `document.getElementById('message').value = "Testmessage at " + new Date();`
- Value : *empty*

Answer (score 0):

Use This -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("source")).sendKeys("ABCD");
```

Comment: I Don't know what problem you are facing. Its working fine at my end.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!